# edit uitextview

Tags: iphone

I want to edit part of the text within the uitextview text (italic bold , ...............) , how to mix between bold and italics and at which formate can I save this eidtable text

I mean how to save the text with this format in txt file

Answer (score 0):

These are actually 2 questions:

Q1: edit part of the text within the uitextview text (italic bold , ...............) 
A1: rich formatting is only available through UIWebView or by overriding the drawRect of your UITextView (ex: manually handle  and  tags by changing the Font)

Q2: save the text with this format in txt file
A2: do you want to load the uitextview's text from a file? If so, you should use a .plist. loading data from a .plist is simple :

```
    NSBundle* bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSString* plistPath = [bundle pathForResource:@"YOUR_FILE_NAME" ofType:@"plist"];
    self.A_DICTIONARY = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
```

Hope this helps

Comment: u mean I save the uitextfield in .plist file , I need text file , and be loaded with the last format itlaic for example